# Different dependencies when starting web application with "Always Start When Debugging"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I start my web application from Visual Studio (2013) using IIS express. If I set it as startup project and start it directly everything works fine.

In the project properties "Always Start When Debugging" is enabled, so the web app also starts when I start my web client in the same solution. But for some reason some dependencies in the webapp\bin directory are exchanged with different version (in this case the Newtonsoft.Json.dll is overwritten with a very old version).

Can someone please explain me the mechanism behind this functionality? Why is my webapp\bin directory touched when I start a different project?

Comment: Are you using "View in Browser" to start the client application? Also, what webapp\bin are you stating is being overwritten, I assume you mean the webapp\bin of the service application?

Comment: @Ross Bush The client application is a WPF application. It uses a System.Net.Http.HttpClient to call the api of the web application. And yes, I mean the webapp\bin of the service application.

Comment: @Ross Bush Just found the solution. The build confuses the bin path. Both projects (webapp and client) have another dependent "framework" project. The framework uses an older version of Newtonsoft.Json.dll (as reference of System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll). The web app additionally uses a newer version of Newtonsoft.Json.dll. So when I build the web app it first builds the framework and then overrides the dll with the newer version. Building the client just builds the framework that leads to writing the old version of the dll to webapp\bin. Excluding the framework from the build helps here.